# Software Deployment for Windows Computers?

Tags: 14.04, windows, microsoft, continuous-deployment

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my workstation. I was given the task to deploy an .msi package to 12 computers and needs to be run silently.

I want to replace SCCM, PDQ Deploy and PDQ Inventory and these are all for Windows OS.

Is there any good Deployment software that I can use to push updated software to other computers on Linux/Ubuntu?

I am not deploying images just single .msi or .exe packages to other Windows machines.

Something like Red Hat Satellite or Spacewalk that supports Windows .msi and .exe packages would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: I will be trying out Zenworks on SLES. If anyone has any more recomendations I will be truly grateful.

https://plus.google.com/104003815827841826615/posts/KRMgYnqLovX

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering and having difficulties:

Novell's Zenworks supports mobile devices, Mac, Windows and Linux.
https://www.novell.com/products/zenworks/endpoint-management/

opsi supports Windows and is Linux Server based.
http://www.opsi.org/en